# Standard Deviation in R Seems to be Returning the Wrong Answer - Am I Doing Something Wrong?

Tags: r, statistics, standard-deviation

A simple example of calculating standard dev:

```
d <- c(2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9)
sd(d)
```

yields

```
[1] 2.13809
```

but when [done by hand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation), the answer is 2. What am I missing here?

Comment: That was exactly the issue. I suppose then, I should assume sd is calculating a sample standard deviation. Thanks for the insight, I appreciate it.

I will be adding this to all my calculations:

    d <- c(2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9);
    n <- length(d);
    sd(d)*sqrt((n-1)/n);

Comment: On that note then, what is the command in R that would produce the standard deviation of the sample, so the N-1 in the denominator would not need to be corrected?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this

```
R> sd(c(2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9)) * sqrt(7/8)
[1] 2
R>
```

and see the rest of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) for the discussion about estimation of standard deviations.  Using the formula employed 'by hand' leads to a biased estimate, hence the correction of sqrt((N-1)/N). Here is a key quote:

> The term standard deviation of the
>   sample is used for the uncorrected
>   estimator (using N) while the term
>   sample standard deviation is used for
>   the corrected estimator (using N − 1).
>   The denominator N − 1 is the number of
>   degrees of freedom in the vector of
>   residuals, .

Comment: After reading the article further, and your comments, I can see why there wouldn't be a function that would produce the biased result. If I want it, I will have to define it, or calculate it myself. Thanks again, spot-on answer.

Comment: *If* you want such a function, it is easy to write as you have `sd()` and you simply need to multiply its result by `sqrt((N-1)/N)` with N being you vector length -- pretty much like my answer but computing `N` as 8.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `sd` also gives biased estimates for standard deviation (see e.g. this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation)). The `N-1` correction is there to ensure that `var` is unbiased.

Comment: The idea that every calculation of a standard deviation is necessarily an estimate seems misguided. I have many applications where I have an entire population sitting in front of me, and not having this function as a standard option in base R seems strange. Yes, it is easy to write my own function, but there is no reason why "there wouldn't be a function that would produce the biased result", because the result itself is not biased. There is a particular estimator that is biased, but not all calculations using that formula are calculations of an estimate using that estimator.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like R is assuming (n-1) in the denominator, not n.

Comment: ouch. You may want to delete that last comment.

Comment: No it isn't. n-1 is the *sample* standard deviation. Divisor n is the *population* standard deviation. The variance would be sd^2, but again, that would be the sample variance as R uses divisor n-1 in `var()`, just as it does in `sd()`. That R uses this divisor is clearly documented on `?sd`

Answer (score 6):

When I want the **population** variance or standard deviation (n as denominator), I define these two vectorized functions.

```
  pop.var <- function(x) var(x) * (length(x)-1) / length(x)

  pop.sd <- function(x) sqrt(pop.var(x))
```

BTW, Khan Academy has a good discussion of **population** and **sample** standard deviation [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/descriptive-statistics/variance_std_deviation/v/sample-standard-deviation-and-bias).

Answer (score 0):

Note that running the command

```
?sd
```

in R Studio displays the help page for the function. In the details section it states

> Like var this uses denominator n - 1.