# different results for standard deviation using numpy and R

Tags: python, r, numpy, statistics

I get two different results when I try to compute the standard deviation with numpy and R .
There is probably something of stupid that I am missing but what?

R code

```
x1=matrix(c(1,7,5,8,9,5,4,5,4,3,76,8),nrow=4)
std=sd(x1[,1])
mean=mean(x1[,1])
std=apply(X=x1,MARGIN=2,FUN=sd)
std



> x1=matrix(c(1,7,5,8,9,5,4,5,4,3,76,8),nrow=4)
> std=sd(x1[,1])
> std=apply(X=x1,MARGIN=2,FUN=sd)
> std
[1]  3.095696  2.217356 35.565667
```

Python code

```
import numpy as np

x1=np.matrix([[1.,9.,4.],[7.,5.,3.],[5.,4.,76.],[8.,5.,8.]])
std=np.apply_along_axis(func1d=np.std,axis=0,arr=x1)


std
Out[9]: array([  2.68095132,   1.92028644,  30.80077109])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get you the same answer as numpy. See [Standard Deviation in R Seems to be Returning the Wrong Answer - Am I Doing Something Wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457755/standard-deviation-in-r-seems-to-be-returning-the-wrong-answer-am-i-doing-some) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation for reference

```
  apply(x1, 2, function(x) sd(x) * sqrt((length(x) - 1) / length(x)) )
```

Answer (score 13):

For future searches, `R` calulates the standard deviation with `N - 1` as the denominator, and `numpy` with `N`. To get the same result try this setting `ddof` (the ["delta degrees of freedom"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) )

```
x1.std(axis=0, ddof=1)
```

Note that you can save a lot of cruft by using different notation:

```
In [33]: x1.std(axis=0)
Out[33]: matrix([[  2.68095132,   1.92028644,  30.80077109]])

In [34]: x1.std(axis=0, ddof=1)
Out[34]: matrix([[  3.09569594,   2.21735578,  35.56566697]])
```

Comment: do you know if there is any variant of sklearn.preprocessing.scale(x1) in order to scale the data using the same definition of standard deviation of R?

Answer (score 4):

By default, R deducts one degree of freedom due to the mean computation in the standard deviation computation.

The NumPy equivalent of the R code is:

```
np.std(x1, axis = 0, ddof = 1)
```