# R equivalent of Numpy.std?

Tags: r, numpy

The standard R sd() function uses a different standard deviation equation than numpy does. R uses the MatLab equation so:

```
>sd(c(1,2,6)
[1] 2.645751
>np.std([1,2,6])
[1] 2.1602468994692869
```

What is an equivalent R function that produces the bottom result?

Comment: `np.std([1,2,6], ddof=1)`

Comment: More on degrees of freedom for SD in R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457755/standard-deviation-in-r-seems-to-be-returning-the-wrong-answer-am-i-doing-some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sd(c(1,2,6))*sqrt(2/3)
[1] 2.160247
```

From that I gather that R uses n-1 in the denominator and numpy uses N when calculating the variance

Comment: And of course `n-1` is usually the more sensible choice.

Comment: Now that I realize it, my data is large enough that the sqrt(n-1/n) is always going to be greater than .999, I think I'll just use sd