# How can I code Vuong's statistical test in Python?

Tags: python, r, statistics, logistic-regression, modeling

I need to implement [Vuong's test](https://doi.org/10.2307/1912557) for non-nested models. Specifically, I have logistic-regression models that I would like to compare.

I have found implementations in R and STATA online, but unfortunately I work in Python and am not familiar with those frameworks/languages. Also unfortunate is that I have not been unable to find a Python implementation of the test (if someone knows of one that would be fantastic!). I asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/606409/301648) and was redirected to here.

After scouring the original paper and a few other pages that I found (references below) I think I've managed to port the R implementation from the [`pscl`](https://github.com/atahk/pscl/blob/master/R/vuong.R). Example code is below.

Is there someone who is fluent in both Python and R who could help confirm that the below code reproduces the R implementation? And, if not, help determine where I erred? In addition to helping with my immediate problem, perhaps this can help someone in the future.

References consulted:

- [Original Vuong Paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/1912557). See page 318 in particular
- [Paper on Misuse](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.econlet.2014.12.029)
- [R `pscl` Implementation](https://github.com/atahk/pscl/blob/master/R/vuong.R)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuong%27s_closeness_test)
- [Matlab User's Implementation](https://github.com/ljchang/CosanlabToolbox/blob/master/Matlab/Stats/vuong.m)
- [Stata User's Implementation](https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/information-criteria-and-vuong-test/#jp-carousel-188)

Example code with current implementation and use for logistic regression fits of dummy data. Note that this is a stock dataset and the predictor variables were arbitrarily selected.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

def vuong_test(mod1, mod2, correction=True):
    '''
    mod1, mod2 - non-nested logitstic regression fit results from statsmodels
    '''
    # number of observations and check of models
    N = mod1.nobs
    N2 = mod2.nobs
    if N != N2:
        raise ValueError('Models do not have the same number of observations')
    # extract the log-likelihood for individual points with the models
    m1 = mod1.model.loglikeobs(mod1.params)
    m2 = mod2.model.loglikeobs(mod2.params)
    # point-wise log likelihood ratio
    m = m1 - m2
    # calculate the LR statistic
    LR = np.sum(m)
    # calculate the AIC and BIC correction factors -> these go to zero when df is same between models
    AICcor = mod1.df_model - mod2.df_model
    BICcor = np.log(N)*AICcor/2
    # calculate the omega^2 term
    omega2 = np.var(m)
    # calculate the Z statistic with and without corrections
    Zs = np.array([LR,LR-AICcor,LR-BICcor])
    Zs /= np.sqrt(N*omega2)
    # calculate the p-value
    ps = []
    msgs = []
    for Z in Zs:
        if Z>0:
            ps.append(1 - norm.cdf(Z))
            msgs.append('model 1 preferred over model 2')
        else:
            ps.append(norm.cdf(Z))
            msgs.append('model 2 preferred over model 1')
    # share information
    print('=== Vuong Test Results ===')
    labs = ['Uncorrected']
    if AICcor!=0:
        labs += ['AIC Corrected','BIC Corrected']
    for lab,msg,p,Z in zip(labs,msgs,ps,Zs):
        print('  -> '+lab)
        print('    -> '+msg)
        print('    -> Z: '+str(Z))
        print('    -> p: '+str(p))

# load sample data
X,y = load_breast_cancer( return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)
# create data for modeling
X1 = sm.add_constant( X.loc[:,('mean radius','perimeter error','worst symmetry')])
X2 = sm.add_constant( X.loc[:,('mean area','worst smoothness')])
# fit the models
mod1 = sm.Logit( y, X1).fit()
mod2 = sm.Logit( y, X2).fit()

# run Vuong's Test
vuong_test( mod1, mod2)
```

Output

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.172071
         Iterations 9
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.156130
         Iterations 9
=== Vuong Test Results ===
  -> Uncorrected
    -> model 2 preferred over model 1
    -> Z: -0.7859538767172318
    -> p: 0.21594725450542168
  -> AIC Corrected
    -> model 2 preferred over model 1
    -> Z: -0.8726045081599004
    -> p: 0.19143934123980472
  -> BIC Corrected
    -> model 2 preferred over model 1
    -> Z: -1.0608044994241501
    -> p: 0.14438937850119132
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to move forward, I learned enough R to be able to make my own comparison between R and python for Vuong's Test as below.

In the end, my original implementation was close except for the subtle point of difference [between how numpy and R calculate standard deviations by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38534101/9963216). After correcting to now calculate the sample standard deviation (by changing `np.var(m)` to `np.var(m,ddof=1)`), I get a match between `pscl` and my own python code.

Updated Python implementation

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

def vuong_test(mod1, mod2, correction=True):
    '''
    mod1, mod2 - non-nested logitstic regression fit results from statsmodels
    '''
    # number of observations and check of models
    N = mod1.nobs
    N2 = mod2.nobs
    if N != N2:
        raise ValueError('Models do not have the same number of observations')
    # extract the log-likelihood for individual points with the models
    m1 = mod1.model.loglikeobs(mod1.params)
    m2 = mod2.model.loglikeobs(mod2.params)
    # point-wise log likelihood ratio
    m = m1 - m2
    # calculate the LR statistic
    LR = np.sum(m)
    # calculate the AIC and BIC correction factors -> these go to zero when df is same between models
    AICcor = mod1.df_model - mod2.df_model
    BICcor = np.log(N)*AICcor/2
    # calculate the omega^2 term
    omega2 = np.var(m, ddof=1)
    # calculate the Z statistic with and without corrections
    Zs = np.array([LR,LR-AICcor,LR-BICcor])
    Zs /= np.sqrt(N*omega2)
    # calculate the p-value
    ps = []
    msgs = []
    for Z in Zs:
        if Z>0:
            ps.append(1 - norm.cdf(Z))
            msgs.append('model 1 preferred over model 2')
        else:
            ps.append(norm.cdf(Z))
            msgs.append('model 2 preferred over model 1')
    # share information
    print('=== Vuong Test Results ===')
    labs = ['Uncorrected']
    if AICcor!=0:
        labs += ['AIC Corrected','BIC Corrected']
    for lab,msg,p,Z in zip(labs,msgs,ps,Zs):
        print('  -> '+lab)
        print('    -> '+msg)
        print('    -> Z: '+str(Z))
        print('    -> p: '+str(p))

# load sample data
X,y = load_breast_cancer( return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)
# create data for modeling
X1 = sm.add_constant( X.loc[:,('mean radius','perimeter error','worst symmetry')])
X2 = sm.add_constant( X.loc[:,('mean area','worst smoothness')])
# fit the models
mod1 = sm.Logit( y, X1).fit()
mod2 = sm.Logit( y, X2).fit()

# run Vuong's Test
vuong_test( mod1, mod2)

# save data for R test function
pd.concat( [X,y], axis=1).to_csv('breast_cancer_data.csv')
```

With output

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.172071
         Iterations 9
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.156130
         Iterations 9
=== Vuong Test Results ===
  -> Uncorrected
    -> model 2 preferred over model 1
    -> Z: -0.7852629281206245
    -> p: 0.21614971334597216
  -> AIC Corrected
    -> model 2 preferred over model 1
    -> Z: -0.8718373831692781
    -> p: 0.19164854872682913
  -> BIC Corrected
    -> model 2 preferred over model 1
    -> Z: -1.0598719238597758
    -> p: 0.1446014350740505
```

Comparison R code

```
# load library
library(pscl)

# load breast cancer data set
bcdata <- read.csv('breast_cancer_data.csv')

# build logistic regression models
mod1 <- glm( target ~ mean.radius + perimeter.error + worst.symmetry, data=bcdata, family="binomial")
mod2 <- glm( target ~ mean.area + worst.smoothness, data=bcdata, family="binomial")

# compare the models
vuong( mod1, mod2)
```

With output

```
Vuong Non-Nested Hypothesis Test-Statistic:
(test-statistic is asymptotically distributed N(0,1) under the
 null that the models are indistinguishible)
-------------------------------------------------------------
              Vuong z-statistic             H_A p-value
Raw                  -0.7852629 model2 > model1 0.21615
AIC-corrected        -0.8718374 model2 > model1 0.19165
BIC-corrected        -1.0598719 model2 > model1 0.14460
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```